# Blank spaces randomly appearing at different places between divs

Tags: html, css

So I'm having a problem that randomly just started happening. I mean that it wasn't a problem yesterday, and today it is.
So, there are blank spaces appearing at random places in my page every time I reload it. There are 3 specific places the blank space happens, but they alternate every time. Note that this doesn't seem to happen on IE, it only happens on Chrome as far as I can tell. Also, when I resize the page even a single pixel, the blank spaces disappear, even if I set it to the original size where the spaces were appearing.

I have already set `* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}` at the start of my CSS file and it doesn't seem to have any effect. The blank spaces still appear.

My CSS file is very long, so I don't think pasting everything here will be useful. But my initial lines look like this:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
html, body {height:100%}
#content {min-height:100%}
#content-inside {padding-bottom:135px}
#footer {height:250px;margin-top:-125px}]

* {font-family:arial;color:#555}
body {background-color: #CDE6BC}
p, h3, h4 {margin-bottom:6px}
h1 {font-size:32px;color:#57783F}
h2 {font-size:24px}
h3 {font-size:19px; font-weight: bold}
h4 {font-size:16px}
p, label, input {font-size:14px}
h2 {color:#57783F}
label {display:block;font-weight:bold}
input {padding:2px}
input[type="text"] {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: url(/cocamar/imagens/fundoCampo.png);
    border: 1px solid rgb(119, 119, 119);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
br {clear:both}
/*a {color:blue;text-decoration:none}
a:hover {color:red;text-decoration:underline}*/

#header {background:#fff;padding:10px;padding-bottom:0px;text-align:center}
#footer {background:#57783F;padding:10px}
#footer * {color:white}
#footer-inside {text-align:center}

.card {padding:10px; position: relative;}
.sub {padding-top:20px;padding-left:10px}
.card {box-shadow:1px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 1px 2px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);margin:5px;background:white;min-height: 275px;}

/* responsive starts here */
* {box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}

.row::after {content:"";clear:both;display:table}

[class*="col-"] {float:left}

[class*="col-"] {width:100%}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-1 {width:8.33%}
    .col-2 {width:16.66%}
    .col-3 {width:25%}
    .col-4 {width:33.33%}
    .col-5 {width:41.66%}
    .col-6 {width:50%}
    .col-7 {width:58.33%}
    .col-8 {width:66.66%}
    .col-9 {width:75%}
    .col-10 {width:83.33%}
    .col-11 {width:91.66%}
    .col-12 {width:100%}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type'  content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' />
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="header-inside">
      <h1>Some Text Here</h1>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="content-inside">  
    <div class='sub'>
      <h2>Some Text Here</h2>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class='col-4'>
      <div class='card'>
        <h3>Some Text Here</h3>
        <p>Some Text Here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'>
      <div class='card'>
        <h3>Some Text Here</h3>
        <p>Some Text Here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-4'>
      <div class='card'>
        <h3>Some Text Here</h3>
        <p>Some Text Here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class='sub'>
    <h2>Some Text here</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='col-12'>
    <div class='card'>
      <h3>Some Text Here</h3>
      <p>Some Text Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class='col-6'>
    <div class='sub'>
      <h2>Some Text Here</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='card'>
      <h3>Some Text Here</h3>
      <p>Some Text Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-6'>
    <div class='sub'>
      <h2>Some Text Here</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='card'>
      <h3>Some Text Here</h3>
      <p>Some Text Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me if anything is missing so I can edit it.

The expected result looks like this:
[image: 1]

But what I'm getting is this:

[image: 1]

[image: 1]

For my "sub" elements, Chrome's Inspect Element is saying this:
[image: 1]

What could be causing this? I haven't added any code since yesterday, but this wasn't happening then, and it's happening now.

Comment: Are you using any javascript to position those boxes? A plugin? Maybe masonry or something similar?

Comment: @JonasGrumann no, only CSS. There is JavaScript, but it doesn't mess with any positioning.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please add enough of the missing markup to the question (I've converted it to a runnable demo for you) so that it reproduces what your screenshots show. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: I believe the code snippet now has the whole basic structure of my website. Note that it's responsive, so maybe resize it to full screen and reload it if possible. As I've said, I can't recreate this issue in IE, it only happens on Chrome and when the window is resized it also disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet does not replicate the issue you're having in your screenshot which makes diagnosing and helping a lot more difficult. That said, I suspect the issue is with the bar going across the SSIs box:

[image: Screenshot]

As your boxes are `float`ing to the left, the box on the right will sit under whatever overflowing content is coming out of the box on the left. Perhaps add `overflow:hidden` to the parent div?

```
.card {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if it does not - it would have to be extremely long otherwise. It's not in my field of knowledge to replicate an issue that I have absolutely no idea how is caused.
With that aside, your solution has solved my problem. `overflow: hidden;` has stopped the cards from going to random places. Thank you.